# How to make an html-file appear on localhost with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Boot and have an html-file "index.html", and I have a class "Functions". Basically, what I want to happen is that when the functions-class is run, and when I go to localhost:8080, the html-template appears at localhost.
How should I do this?

Here is a segment of the Functions-class:

```
public class Functions{
   @RequestMapping("/")
   public void getHomepage(){
      //Return the html-template
   }
```

}

The html-file is called "index.html" and is in the src/main/resources/static-folder.

Thank you!

Comment: put `return "index";` in the body of the `getHomepage()` method. See this [Spring Web MVC Getting Started](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) tutorial. Templates should be in `src/main/resources/templates` instead of `src/main/resources/static`.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I will try that now

Comment: @Jesper has right. I created a project based on this tutorial, and it was very helpful: https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-web-application-part-1-spring-initializr/

Comment: Mind that you have to change the return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, put the `index.html` template file in `src/main/resources/templates` instead of in `src/main/resources/static`.

Your class `Functions` must be a Spring MVC controller; you can make it a controller by adding the `@Controller` annotation. Return the name of the template in the `getHomepage()` method:

```
@Controller
public class Functions {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getHomepage() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

This is all basic Spring Web MVC; see a tutorial like this [Serving Web Content](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) guide on the Spring website and the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-web).

Comment: I will take a detailed look at the tutorial.

For now when I changed the return type to String, added @Controller, and put "index.html" in "templates". However, when I just copy your code and go to localhost, it just says index on the screen. Like a String. I still don't see the html.

Comment: Did you use `@RestController` or `@ResponseBody` on class `Functions` or method `getHomepage()`, or did you modify the Spring configuration so that it doesn't work the default way?

Comment: Thank you for another reply! I have not done any of those things. 

It seems like Spring Boot is not recognizing Tymeleaf, even though I put in the spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency in maven. When I go to the html file and look at the namespace xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org", it says that the namespace declaration is never used.

Comment: That doesn't matter, it just means you don't have any `<th:...>` tags in your template - it does not mean that Spring Boot does not find Thymeleaf. Without seeing the exact structure and setup of your project, I can't tell what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information! And for all the help, I will keep searching for what went wrong :)

Comment: It was actually a @RestController that made things crash. Now it works! :D Have a good day!