# Spring-boot restapi page call

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I got a simple spring boot application. I am trying load the html file through a rest controller. Below is my folder structure. I am unable to load test.html (just as helloworld code inside it)

[image]

```
@RequestMapping("/show1")
public ModelAndView showpage1() {
    System.out.println("## show1");
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
     modelAndView.setViewName("test");
     return modelAndView;
}
```

My test.html content

```
<h1> hello World </h1>
```

Comment: Would you update your answer with POM.xml as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40766349/4214241 . You probably are missing the right dependency

Comment: please go throw the following reference. [stackoverflow.com/questions/38221461](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221461/how-to-make-an-html-file-appear-on-localhost-with-spring-boot)

Comment: What is the template engine you are using? It will not work if you are not adding Template engine dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
 @RequestMapping("/show1")
            public String showpage1() {
                return "test";
            }
```

where test.html is your page

Comment: Oh sorry you have added /show1 in your RequestMapping, so pls check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return the string with the name of the view.

```
@RequestMapping("/showpage")
public String showpage1() {
      return "test";
}
```